# Magento 2: 403 error after issuing setup:upgrade command

Tags: magento2, frontend, permissions, apache2, http-status-403

I have set 777 permissions for `pub/` and `var/` directories.
I have run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.
A 403 error is displayed when accessing any page on the website with the following message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: show the error details here after upgrade command

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 : open the terminal and navigate to magento web root

> cd /var/www/html/magento2

Step 2 : Deploy command

> php bin/magento s:s:d

Step 3 : Reindex command

> php bin/magento i:rei

Step 4 : Set owner command

> chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2

Step 5 : Give permission command

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2

Step 6 : Remove cache command

> rm -rf var/cache

Comment: Rohan Hapani@perfect , but can you exaplin this chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2

Comment: These permissions apply to that user and group who has special access to the file. chown -R your_user_name:your_user_group_name /var/www/html/magento2 for set

Comment: please upvote on answer. So, it will useful for other user.

Comment: @RohanHapani How can i solve 403 in Rest API error : https://snag.gy/TY8nJ1.jpg, if i try with http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products/ it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command after setup:upgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Prashant Valanda@I did but still facing 403 issue, this issue only run when i run upgrade comond

Comment: have you given permission to pub folder after run static content deploy command?

Comment: Prashant Valanda@yes i given  777 permission

Comment: when you load any page it shows any error ?

Comment: @PrashantValanda How can i solve 403 in Rest API error : https://snag.gy/TY8nJ1.jpg, if i try with http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products/ it is working.

Comment: @zus you need to create user in backend generate token and pass it to header

Comment: @PrashantValanda By using postman it is working, how can i pass my all values to url, postman o/p-> https://postimg.cc/67x3Vmqr     &    https://postimg.cc/JHsMCNt7

Comment: please check it: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-custom-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

When U Install Magento That time Not Add The Js file in pub folder
if u Run below command than all Js and templates file deploy in pub Folder

now run this command step by step

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: How can i solve 403 in Rest API error : https://snag.gy/TY8nJ1.jpg, if i try with http://127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products/ it is working. @Rasik